# Changing icons to images

Tags: icons, tiles

Thank you for reading my question.

I'm a total rookie with Flutter but trying to learn and understand the code.

At this moment I'm trying to change an app layout. This app is showing 4 rows with 3 tiles in each row. In the tiles are icons showing. I want to change the icons into images.

The code for the icons is in two dart files. You can see a part of the code that is creating the tile and it is referring to another dartfile where for each tile the icon names are in the code.

How can I change this code so it is not referring to icons but to images?

**Here is a part of the first dart file where tiles are created with icons inside**

```
child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              const Spacer(
                flex: 2,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 10,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: FittedBox(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: Icon(
                    tileInformation.icon, <-----------------------
                    size: 36,
                    color: AppConstants.iconColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(
                flex: 2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**Here is a part of the other dart file were the icon names are**

```
  TileInformation(
  tileDe_gemeente,
  Icons.location_city_outlined, <-----------------------------------
  TileType.webpage,
  url: "//justalink/",
),
TileInformation(
  tileWaar,
  Icons.follow_the_signs_outlined,  <------------------------------
  TileType.webpage,
  url: "/justalink//",
),
TileInformation(
  tileAgenda,
  Icons.auto_stories_outlined , <--------------------------------
  TileType.webpage,
  url: "//justalink/",
),
```

**If I replace this line:**

```
    child: Icon(
                    tileInformation.icon,
                    size: 36,
                    color: AppConstants.iconColor
```

**To this line:**

```
    child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/icon.png"),
```

**Then the tiles are showing all the same images. So my problem is how to use the second dart file to choose a different image for every tile.**